# Disable input in table row if one of input filled

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have javascript code to disable other inputs if one is filled .
I need it in table that comes out of database.
The sad thing is that it only works with first table row and disable all inputs in table (but if input filled is not first nothing happens)

Javascript:

```
  $(function(){
    $("input").on("keyup", function(){
            if($(this).hasClass("inputA") && $(".inputA").val()){
               $("input.inputB").prop("disabled", true);
               $("input.inputA").prop("disabled", false);
               $("input.inputC").prop("disabled", true);

            } else if($(this).hasClass("inputB") && $(".inputB").val()){
               $("input.inputA").prop("disabled", true);
                $("input.inputB").prop("disabled", false);
                 $("input.inputC").prop("disabled", true);

            } else if($(this).hasClass("inputC") && $(".inputC").val()){
               $("input.inputA").prop("disabled", true);
                $("input.inputB").prop("disabled", true);
                 $("input.inputC").prop("disabled", false);

            }  else {
                       $(".inputA, .inputB").prop("disabled", false);

                    }
    });
});
```

My td from html table:

```
<td><input type="text" class="inputA" value=""></td>
<td><input type="text" class="inputB" value=""></td>
<td><input type="text" class="inputC" value=""></td>
```

How to make it work for each line separated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same `class` on each `input`, create event on those `input` after that check the `value` of the input if she's not empty `disable` all of others `input` for this works in a line just select all input of the `parent`.

Try to avoid multiple test as you did. Not lisible and maintainable.

**Example**

```js
$(".input").on("keypress change keyup",function(){
   if($(this).val() != "")
   {
     $(this).parent().parent().find(".input").not($(this)).prop("disabled",true);
   }
   else
   {
     $(this).parent().parent().find(".input").prop("disabled",false);
   }
});
```

```css
.input:disabled{
  background-color:LightBlue;
  border:solid 1px blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="input" value="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="input" value="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="input" value="">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="input" value="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="input" value="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="input" value="">
    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: This is good example but this disable all other inputs in table not just in current line

Comment: Any idea how to make disabled inputs change color?

Comment: Thanks !I would probably use javascript and would mess your code :D

Comment: any idea how to make it disable number 1 and number 2 inputs when using 2 or four ?struggling whit this last few hours :(

Answer (score 1):

This solves your issue! Disable all input fields that doesn't have same class as the one being currently edited.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/3tf8ou3y/1/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("tr").on("keyup", "input", function(event) {
        // get the current row
        var $row = $(event.delegateTarget);
        // get the class of the input field being edited
        var this_class = $(this).attr('class');

        if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
            // if the input field has a value, disable all
            // other input fields in the sam row
            $('input:not(.'+this_class+')', $row).prop('disabled', true);
        } else {
            // else enable all input fields
            $('input', $row).prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'jQuery(this).val()' instead of 'jQuery(".inputA").val()' or 'jQuery(".inputB").val()' or jQuery(".inputC").val()